# .htaccess adding part into url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, addition

I am puzzeling with this issue for a while now. The website will become multilangual. 
I try to add `/nl-nl/` to the URL if this parameter is not in the URL.

So for example:
`https://www.sample.com/page1`
-to-
`https://www.sample.com/nl-nl/page1`

My current lines are:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)([a-z-]{5})(.*)`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/nl-nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

But the url ends up with: `https://www.sample.com/nl-nl/404`

I hope someone sees what I didn't see. :)

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/nl-nl/$1 [L,R=301]`. `HTTP_HOST` is the host name used in the request, usually using that makes more sense than the server name. (Page could have been reached via a different alias domain.) And `$1` is just the part you captured with the RewriteRule pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes more sense now. I still get the 404 page but the URL stays like ```https://www.sample.com/page1``` (So it does not redirect to ```https://www.sample.com/nl-nl/page1```

Comment: Not sure that RewriteCond pattern makes that much sense, you are allowing _anything_ before and after `[a-z-]{5}`. Even `bo-ob` anywhere in the middle or end of the URL would match that. That pattern should at least be anchored at the start, something like `^/[a-z-]{5}` would make more sense here, maybe even demanding a `/` after that as well.

Comment: Ok changed that to ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-z-]{5})/```. Is there a way to check the value of ```%{REQUEST_URI}```? Now the page redirects to ```sample.com/nl-nl/index.php?lng=en-us&do=404``` I have these lines at the bottom of the htaccess: ```ErrorDocument 404 /en-us/404 ErrorDocument 403 /en-us/403```

Comment: Nothing in what you have shown so far redirects to `index.php?lng=…`, so there must be additional parts to this we have not been shown yet.